# How to create markdown snippets in atom.

Tags: atom-editor

Anyone know how? I am trying this but it doesn't work:

````
'text.html.markdown':
  'Bash':
    'prefix': '`B'
    'body': '```Bash\n\n```'
  'rubyonrails':
    'prefix': '`r'
    'body': '```rubyonrails\n\n($1)```'
````

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default scope for Markdown in Atom is `.source.gfm`, not `text.html.markdown`.

Your snippets would look like:

````coffee
'.source.gfm':
  'Bash':
    'prefix': '`B'
    'body': '```Bash\n\n```'
  'rubyonrails':
    'prefix': '`r'
    'body': '```rubyonrails\n\n($1)```'
````

Answer (score 3):

The scope depends on the language (package) you are using:

- **language-markdown**: `.text.md`
- **language-gfm**: `.source.gfm`

You can combine both selectors to cover both cases:

````coffee
'.text.md, .source.gfm':
  'Bash':
    'prefix': '`B'
    'body': '```Bash\n\n```'
  'rubyonrails':
    'prefix': '`r'
    'body': '```rubyonrails\n\n($1)```'
````

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `'.source.gfm'` to  `'.text.md'` in order to get this to work for me.

Note sure if this had any bearing on it but I'm using these markdown-related packages: language-markdown, markdown-writer, markdown-preview, markdown-scroll-sync